# How do I calculate this sum $\sum_k(k!)^{-n}$?

Tags: nt.number-theory, co.combinatorics, combinatorial-identities

How do I evaluate the following finite sum over $k$

$1+\frac{1}{2^n}+\frac{1}{2^n3^n}+\frac{1}{2^n3^n4^n}+\cdots+\frac{1}{2^n3^n\cdots k^n}$

or if there is an expression of this sum in terms of other known numbers ??

Comment: $\sum_{k=0}^\infty(k!)^{-n}$ is open at https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2902724. Or do you mean the finite sum?

Comment: the sum is finite over $k$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$${}_1F_n(1;2,2,\ldots 2; 1) - \frac{{}_1F_{n}(1;2+k,2+k,\ldots 2+k; 1)}{((k+1)!)^n} $$

Comment: and what about the finite case

Comment: This is the finite case.

Comment: well thanks, can I express it in terms of generalized harmonic numbers or multiple harmonic sums ??

Comment: What is denoted by $_1F_n$? How is that obtained?

Comment: You can see the definition in wikipedia   https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypergeometric_function

Comment: @user143983: Why do you think so? The notations differ.

Comment: $_pF_q$ is a so called "generalized hypergeometric function". See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generalized_hypergeometric_function. In this case it is more or less just a short hand notation for your sum. But many results exist about generalized hypergeometric functions, which might help you with your research.